# merging columns from one DataFrame to another

Tags: r, dataframe

I am New to R and was trying to pick columns from one dataframe and insert them in another like this below.

```
m1_row_col_values <-paste(cp1$year,"-",cp1$Location,"",cp1$Trait),cp1$row,cp1$Column,cp1$Value#row_col_values
```

the first column was supposed to be a aggregate name that I paste together.

taking columns from cp1 and inserting them into  m1_row_col_values

this didn't work how do you do it?

Here is a link to the data and the lines I am trying to get working:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17WYto0Y4SM3Ojfch-syh5AmJCikByPKx/view?usp=sharing

```
cp1 = read.csv("cp1s.csv")

m1_row_col_values <-paste(cp1$year,"-",cp1$Location,"-",cp1$Trait),cp1$row,cp1$Column,cp1$Value#row_col_values
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `unite` from `tidyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
cp1_new <- cp1 %>% 
  unite(name, "Year", "Location", "Trait", sep = "-") %>% 
  select(name, Row, Column, Value)
```

**data (head):**

```
cp1 <- structure(list(Record = c(521, 521, 521, 521, 521, 521), Plot = c(101, 
101, 101, 101, 101, 101), Row = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Column = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Cp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Csp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), Entry = c(521, 521, 521, 521, 521, 521), Year = c(2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), Location = c("Preston", "Preston", 
"Preston", "Preston", "Preston", "Preston"), Genotype = c("NxB-RIL-368-16", 
"NxB-RIL-368-16", "NxB-RIL-368-16", "NxB-RIL-368-16", "NxB-RIL-368-16", 
"NxB-RIL-368-16"), Trait = c("STD", "V1", "V2", "V3", "W1", "W2"
), Value = c(2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 5), id = c("2019_Preston_NxB-RIL-368-16", 
"2019_Preston_NxB-RIL-368-16", "2019_Preston_NxB-RIL-368-16", 
"2019_Preston_NxB-RIL-368-16", "2019_Preston_NxB-RIL-368-16", 
"2019_Preston_NxB-RIL-368-16")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments